# Would this method of looping be a bad idea?

Tags: c++

I'm building a html/xml slicer (something that cuts the text into a list of meaningful blocks like elementStart, plainText etc.. which I can then use to construct the elements in an OO manner).

I found it convenient to create a logic sub for processing each of the various modes, the main loop info is held in class variables while the sub's do some work and then pass the torch to another one depending on what data they encounter. It occurred to me though, that this might cause some problems (like overflowing the stack? idk) since technically, it doesn't exit a single one of the subs until the entire process is complete. Heres what I mean: (in pseudo code)

```
void plainLogic() {
    // look for '<' with something other than space after it
    // add the gathered data to the slice list
    switch (data[it])  // <- the something other
    {
        case '!':
            commentLogic();
            break;
        case '/':
            elEndLogic();   
            break;
        default:
            elStartLogic();
            break;
    }         
}
```

and the other *Logic subs are pretty much the same: find the extent of data, bag the goods, go somewhere else. I realized just a little while ago though, that it doesn't actually go anywhere, it just goes deeper and actually has to come back.

Is this bad? Would it be Ok if none of the subs had any sub scope variables? preferred alternatives? Maybe there is like a special return keyword that executes another function after exiting the sub?

Comment: You might want to use a dispatch table, or look at state machine design patterns.

Comment: The specific function you are showing is only using [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) which a compiler can optimize away to not fill up the stack.  But using recursion is a very common technique in compiler engineering.  It is probably unfeasible to avoid.  If you are worried about being exploited, maybe set a sanity limit and reject the input if is too deeply nested.

Comment: @5gon12eder A compiler *can* optimize away tail calls, but there is no guarantee that it will, and if it doesn't stack overflow is a real problem. It is certainly feasible to avoid recursion in an XML parser. I would even call it a good idea, particularly if recursion would lead you to putting in an unnecessary depth limit.

Comment: Currently I ended up setting a class scope state value instead of going into another sub and all the subs return to a main loop sub that then executes the next sub based on the state. One extra switch statement between each state change but shouldn't make a noticeable difference to the performance.